# Loop function to calculate for y in python

Tags: python, iteration

I would like to run this calculation from x = 0 to x++. It will stop when y = 0.5 and return x value, I don't know how to write loop function by python in the right way. Can anybody help me?

```
y = ((x-1) * (x-2) * (x-3) * (x-4) * (x-5) * (x-6))/x^6
```

I use this code but It not work like i thought

```
x = 0
while x > 0:
    print ("The percent is", y)
    x += 1
    y = ((x-1) * (x-2) * (x-3) * (x-4) * (x-5) * (x-6))/x**6
    if round(y,1) == 0.5:
        print (x)
```

Comment: x =0 and while condition is x>0, your while don't run

Comment: Your condition is `when y=0.5` so why are you putting the exit condition `x > 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I would like to write a function that return x when we know y = 0.5. How I can change this code into the right way ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this will help you :

```
x = 1
while x > 0:
    
    y = ((x-1) * (x-2) * (x-3) * (x-4) * (x-5) * (x-6))/x**6
    print ("The percent is", y)
    x += 1
    if round(y) > 0.5:
        print("the value of x is:", x)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really help me how this loop works

Comment: x value is 29 when y is 0.5 and your code print 34 which is not correct method

Comment: because I use > instead of == , I don't know if he want to take the value 0.5 or not , any way my method is correct   as yours

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1
while x > 0:
    y = round(((x-1) * (x-2) * (x-3) * (x-4) * (x-5) * (x-6))/x**6, 1)
    if y == 0.5:
        print (x)
        break
     x += 1
```

you can also verify the answer like below

```
x = 29
y = round(((x-1) * (x-2) * (x-3) * (x-4) * (x-5) * (x-6))/x**6, 1)
print(y)
```